# Parse URLs of Java Script on iPhone with Hpple

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, xcode, html-parsing

I'm trying to extract the urls from a .htm source, that contains 3 other urls inside a java script code.I'm trying to use Hpple.

How to parse on the iPhone the URLs under **'file'** on the **.htm** source code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mydomain/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='container'>Player should appear here</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
jwplayer('container').setup({
'flashplayer': 'http://mydomain/directory1/jwplayer/player.swf',
'controlbar.position': 'bottom',
'controlbar.idlehide': 'false',
'width': '550',
'height': '300',
'autostart': 'true',
'icons': 'true',


'playlist': [{
'file': 'http://http://mydomain/directory1/english/audio1.m4a', 
},{ 
    'file': 'http://http://mydomain/directory1/english/audio2.m4a', 
},{ 
'file': 'http://http://mydomain/directory1english/audio3.m4a', 
}],
repeat: 'list'


});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Winston- hello sir , i Have same problem i follow your way,,please tell me how can solve your problem i can't solve it :(

Comment: Hi iPatel, I'm using RaptureXML to parse the HTML content, then I'm using Regex to grab the needed urls. I could send you some code, if that helps you.

Comment: @Winston..many many thanks for replay ..please send me code at on axxxita07@gmail.com and also see my Q-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128700/get-specific-value-between-javascript-function-by-nsregularexpression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of the `<script>` tag aren't HTML, so hpple won't be able to parse it. What you want to do is to use hpple to get the contents of the `<script>` tag:

```
TFHpple *doc = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:data];
NSString *scriptElement = [[doc searchWithXPathQuery:@"//script"] lastObject];
NSString *scriptContent = [scriptElement content];
```

Then use a [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get those URLs out of there.

Comment: hello sir , i Have same problem i follow your way,,please tell me how can solve your problem i can't solve it :(